# Heat kernel: DeWitt iterative procedure

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

The DeWitt ansatz for the heat kernel is given by

$$K(t ; x, y ; D)=(4 \pi t)^{-n / 2} \Delta_{V V M}^{1 / 2}(x, y) \exp \left(-\frac{\sigma(x, y)}{2 t}\right) \Xi(t ; x, y ; D)$$
where $\sigma$ is the Synge's world function, $\Delta_{V V M}$ is the Van Vleck-Morte determinant. Due to the heat equation

$$(\partial_t + D)K(t ; x, y ; D) = 0$$ one obtains

$$\left(\partial_{t}+t^{-1}\left(\nabla^{\mu} \sigma\right) \nabla_{\mu}+\Delta_{V V M}^{-1 / 2} D \Delta_{V V M}^{1 / 2}\right) \Xi=0$$ where $D$ is some linear differential operator. Does anyone know how this happens ? (Ref. Eq. (4.37)-(4.39) Sec. 4.3 of https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0306138)

Comment: I think sec. 9.3 of these lecture notes by Omar Zanusso could be helpful http://www.tpi.uni-jena.de/~omza/notes-omar.pdf .

Comment: @WeatherReport Thank you for making me aware of these notes. Certainly, some of the details in these notes will help me derive the above myself, but it would still be nice to have the above derived for me as well as for others.

Comment: @Nikita $D$ has a form $-g^{\mu\nu}(\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}+C)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am only getting a partial answer. Here is what and how I am getting:
$D$ is of form $-g^{\mu\nu}(\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}+C)$ where $C$ is some constant, given in section 1 of the paper. I will take $C$ to be $0$ (zero) in the following also I will strip away all constant, which can be stripped, from $K$ for the ease of typing:
$$K(t ; x, y ; D)=\frac{1}{t^{n / 2}}\Delta^{1 / 2}\exp \left(-\frac{\sigma}{2 t}\right) \Xi$$
$$(\partial_t + D)K(t ; x, y ; D)=\partial_tK+DK$$
For the first term
$$\partial_tK=-\frac{n}{2t}\frac{1}{t^{n / 2}}\Delta^{1 / 2}\exp \left(-\frac{\sigma}{2 t}\right) \Xi+\frac{\sigma}{2t^2}\frac{1}{t^{n / 2}}\Delta^{1 / 2}\exp \left(-\frac{\sigma}{2 t}\right) \Xi+\frac{1}{t^{n / 2}}\Delta^{1 / 2}\exp \left(-\frac{\sigma}{2 t}\right)\Big(\partial_t \Xi\Big)$$
while the second term
$$DK=-\frac{1}{t^{n/2}}g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}\bigg(\Big(\Delta^{1 / 2}\Xi\Big)\exp \left(-\frac{\sigma}{2 t}\right) \bigg)$$
$$=-\frac{g^{\mu\nu}}{t^{n/2}}\Bigg(\exp \left(-\frac{\sigma}{2 t}\right)\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}\Big(\Delta^{1 / 2}\Xi\Big)+2\nabla_{\mu}\bigg[\exp \left(-\frac{\sigma}{2 t}\right)\bigg]\nabla_{\nu}\Big(\Delta^{1 / 2}\Xi\Big)+\Big(\Delta^{1 / 2}\Xi\Big)\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}\exp \left(-\frac{\sigma}{2 t}\right)\Bigg)$$

$$=\frac{1}{t^{n/2}}\Bigg(\exp \left(-\frac{\sigma}{2 t}\right)D\Big(\Delta^{1 / 2}\Xi\Big)-
2\bigg[-\frac{1}{2t}\exp \left(-\frac{\sigma}{2 t}\right)\nabla_{\mu}\sigma\bigg]\nabla^{\mu}\Big(\Delta^{1 / 2}\Xi\Big)+\Big(\Delta^{1 / 2}\Xi\Big)D\exp \left(-\frac{\sigma}{2 t}\right)\Bigg)$$
$$=\frac{1}{t^{n/2}}\Bigg(\exp \left(-\frac{\sigma}{2 t}\right)D\Big(\Delta^{1 / 2}\Xi\Big)+\frac{1}{t}\bigg[\exp \left(-\frac{\sigma}{2 t}\right)\nabla_{\mu}\sigma\bigg]\nabla^{\mu}\Big(\Delta^{1 / 2}\Xi\Big)-\frac{1}{2t}\Big(\Delta^{1 / 2}\Xi\Big)\exp \left(-\frac{\sigma}{2 t}\right)D\sigma\Bigg)$$
The second term can be expanded using $\nabla^{\mu}\Big(\Delta^{1 / 2}\Xi\Big)=\Xi\nabla^{\mu}\Delta^{1 / 2}+\Delta^{1 / 2}\nabla^{\mu}\Xi$. Now collecting all terms and cancelling $\frac{1}{t^{n/2}}\exp(-\sigma/2t)$ we get

$$-\frac{n}{2t}\Delta^{1/2}\Xi+\frac{\sigma}{2t^2}\Delta^{1/2}\Xi+\Delta^{1/2}\partial_t\Xi+D\Big(\Delta^{1/2}\Xi\Big)+t^{-1}\nabla_{\mu}\sigma\Big(\Xi\nabla^{\mu}\Delta^{1 / 2}+\Delta^{1 / 2}\nabla^{\mu}\Xi\Big)-\frac{1}{2t}\Big(\Delta^{1/2}\Xi\Big)D\sigma=0$$
multiplying both side by $\Delta^{-1/2}$  we get

$$-\frac{n}{2t}\Xi+\frac{\sigma}{2t^2}\Xi+\partial_t\Xi+\Delta^{-1/2}D\Big(\Delta^{1/2}\Xi\Big)+t^{-1}\nabla_{\mu}\sigma\Big(\Xi\Delta^{-1/2}\nabla^{\mu}\Delta^{1 / 2}+\nabla^{\mu}\Xi\Big)-\frac{1}{2t}\Big(\Xi\Big)D\sigma=0$$

$$\implies \partial_t\Xi+\Delta^{-1/2}D\Big(\Delta^{1/2}\Xi\Big)+t^{-1}\nabla_{\mu}\sigma\nabla^{\mu}\Xi+\bigg[-\frac{n}{2t}\Xi+\frac{\sigma}{2t^2}\Xi+t^{-1}\nabla_{\mu}\sigma\Xi\Delta^{-1/2}\nabla^{\mu}\Delta^{1/2}-\frac{1}{2t}\Xi D\sigma\bigg]=0$$

$$\big(\partial_t+t^{-1}(\nabla^{\mu}\sigma)\nabla_{\mu}+\Delta^{-1/2}D\Delta^{1/2}\big)\Xi+
\bigg[-\frac{n}{2t}\Xi+\frac{\sigma}{2t^2}\Xi+\frac{1}{2t}\sigma\Xi\Delta^{-1}\nabla_{\mu}\sigma\nabla^{\mu}\Delta-\frac{1}{2t}\Xi D\sigma\bigg]=0$$
The expression in $[...]$ has to be $0$ (zero), which is something I can't prove, embarrassingly not even for Minkowski space ($\Delta=\eta^{\mu\nu}$ and $\sigma=(x-y)^2/2$). You can check [this reference](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9303020) for some identities of $\Delta_{VVM}$ to bash with expression in $[...]$. Since I'm not well familiarized with heat kernels, I can't say with surety but $t$ has to have some relation with $\sigma$ for the second expression to drop.

Comment: I am most grateful. Actually, even I am getting something this close, but I am grateful that you tried and confirmed some of my ideas to be as correct.